# HTML from PHP has some undesired, excessive indentation

Tags: php, html, indentation

I'd like to control exactly the indentation of my HTML that's generated by PHP but I'm unable to remove some of it. An example is this HTML source code:

```
<table id="structure">
<tr>
    <td id="navigation">
        <p>Hello!</p>   </td>
```

Why are the `<td>` and `<p>` lines indented like this? Can I modify that?

The main PHP that generated it was

```
<table id="structure">
<tr>
<td id="navigation"><?php echo navigation($data_page,$data_subj);?>
```

and the "navigation" function starts with

```
function navigation($data_page,$data_subj){
$output = "<p>Hello!</p>";
return $output;
}
```

(The real navigation is a `<ul>` with `<li>` elements containing `<ul>`'s in turn and I'm trying to render it readable in the HTML source code by adding `\n` and `\t\t` for indentation levels.)

Comment: So you are looking for nice structured html? Why? You could use FireBug for that. Also it is useless to do this.

Comment: @Bondye I'd like to have readable HTML source code because if I see something nasty in the browser, I want to quickly identify what's going on. It also facilitates keeping track on the exact output from PHP.

Comment: Creating perfect HTML from PHP-interspersed source is virtually impossible. You may want to look at templating languages like Twig, but even those aren't perfect when it comes to includes and the like. It's really an uphill battle. If you care that much, run the generated HTML through Tidy or something like that.

Comment: @pythonforspss.org Like i said, Use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) from [FireFox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) for that. Or [Google Chrome developer](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

Comment: @Bondye thx, perhaps Chrome Developer may be useful here.

Answer (score -1):

For new line try '\r\n'.
The sign for new line is depends on your file encoding and the operating system you are using.

Comment: You mean "replace \n by \r\n", and just leave the "\t"'s as they are, right? Encoding = UTF-8, OS = Windows XP (sorry my laptop is rather old) and I'm using Notepad++ for writing.